# How to remove one item from a list without affecting the rest?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a list on my database that is like this:

```
Test,Test2,Test3
```

I need an way to remove one text of this list without affecting the others. Like this

```
Test,Test3
```

How can i do that? Do I need to `explode` and then remove it or can I just do that with query on MySQL? OBS: I use MySQL not MySQLi

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried writing any code yet? Please review [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: It's not good? Lol, can you help me to change?

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "a list on my database that is like this:Test,Test2,Test3"? What are the columns and how many rows are we talking about here?

Comment: @DotComBoy I can't. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of things in a string.  Lists should (generally) be stored as tables in relational databases.

Comment: @Grady it's just 1 line and i use explode to get one player of that list, understand? Srry bad english

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know but i need and prefer to do that list in just one table like this: Blabla;BlaBla2;BlaBla3 and then use explode to get one of that list..

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's because i have too many players/users registered and i don't want to have Tables and Tables..

Comment: It's high time you changed your DB design. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @1000111 I understand, but in my list I do not use numbers with sequences, I just used it here to understand it better, my only concern in putting in just one column the list is that maybe the return of the list with explode may be a bit more time consuming, else if do I create another table with columns it's more faster right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(your_column, 'Test2', '') AS your_alias
FROM 
    your_table;
```

or

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(your_column, 'Test2', '')
FROM
    your_table;
```

Comment: Hello, i use this: `$a = $this->db->query("SELECT REPLACE('Test1,Test2,Test3', 'Test2', '') AS amigoslista FROM rede_geral WHERE nome='LewBr'"); ` but it don't do nothing here.. it keeps whit Test1,Test2,Test3...

Comment: The true way is `REPLACE(your_column, 'Test2', '')`. Not `REPLACE('Test1,Test2,Test3', 'Test2', '')`

Comment: Nice, but i need to update that... on var_dump i receive that true, but has an way to update and set that on database?

Comment: You can do like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306393/3728901 . **SELECT** data from database, assign result to an array. Get element from arrays of result, put it to **UPDATE** query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **REPLACE** function

```
SELECT REPLACE('Test,Test2,Test3','Test2','');
```

For query from table;

```
SELECT REPLACE(YourColumn,'Test2','') from YourTable
```

Comment: I have tryed this but i don't know why but doesn't work.. I have tryed doing that: $this->db->query("SELECT list FROM database REPLACE('Test,Test2,Test3','Test2','')");

Comment: Please explain more about the code, so future visitors will not get lost.

Comment: It should work that? $this->db->query("SELECT list FROM database REPLACE('Test,Test2,Test3','Test2','')");

Comment: This would also replace entries like `'Test21', 'OtherTest2'` etc. -- and also leave in a double ',,' comma. Rather replace `(YourColumn, ',Text2,', ',')`. However for that you need to have leading and trailing commas in the list. Lists stored as strings make for ugliness.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in 2 steps. The idea is the following:

1. Get the list, explode, remove the `Test 2`, then implode

Here, you should already be getting `Test,Test3`

2. `UPDATE` the row of that database with the new String from the implode

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: How i remove Test2?